# Use css class/id from JSON key

Tags: javascript, json, get, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm fairly new to JSON and the json file I'm working with has HTML elements in certain keys. Here's an example of data in an array I'm trying to pull.

```
"com" : "<p class=\"body-line ltr \"><span class=\"heading\">HEADING</span></p><p class=\"body-line ltr \">BODY</p>"
```

As expected, when it's pulled onto the page it's just displayed as text:

```
"<p class="body-line ltr "><span class="heading">HEADING</span></p><p class="body-line ltr ">BODY</p>"
```

How can I remove the HTML elements from the text and use them in my own web page? Keeping in mind that I can't actually edit the json file.

I'm using vue and vue resource.

Comment: Do you only want the class names, which you plan to inject into a dynamically generated CSS file of some sort that will contain classes with those names and your own definitions for them? Or you want to display the full <p> element (as per your example, not saying limited to that one element) as an actual element on your HMTL page? It is a bit difficult to understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to explain it better: my css file will be static. i'll just create classes to match what's being pulled in from json.


ie: i'll just create classes for `.body-line .ltr` in the header and then when the data is pulled into my app the `<p>` class is hidden in html.

Comment: so what are you trying to do, display the `<p>` element as-is from the data in the json? (meaning, have it become a part of the DOM rather than a text on the page)

Comment: Yes; exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I know what you're asking --

> You need to actually add the element to the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in order for it to show up as HTML on your page; until then, it is just a string.

There are many ways to do this, such as [jQuery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) if you use `jQuery`, or [document.appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) if you have an object and want to use **plain old JavaScript**, or you can also set the `innerHTML` of an element using JavaScript to include the new contents.

---

**I will provide one example here, using plain JS and innerHTML of a Div.**

You get json from somewhere that looks like:

```
json = { "com" : "some HTML in here" }
```

You might have container some div like this on the page:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Then, wherever your JavaScript is, you could set the innerHTML of the container:

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("container")
containerDiv.innerHTML = json["com"]
```

This should give you enough direction to roll with this.

Here's my small example working in a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/16pcayjq/

Comment: Perfect! I looked into using `innerHTML` with Vue and it lead me to  the `v-html` directive which is exactly what I was looking to accomplish.